# get tags in docker registry response using shell script

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I use:

`curl -X GET "192.168.50.117:5000/v2/internet-crawler/tags/list`

to list tags of internet-crawler image and have response:

`{"name":"internet-crawler","tags":["2.9.6","2.8.0"]}`

How can I get 2.9.6 in tags using file sh in Ubuntu?

Comment: i just want 2.9.6 to set variable in sh file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string. It's better to use command line tools such as [`jq`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/jq.1.html) to manipulate JSON. To install `jq`, run

```
sudo apt install jq
```

In your the response, you have "tags" array and 2.9.6 is at index 0. To get that, you can parse the response to `jq` and use `r` flag. Example usage:

```
$ curl -X GET "192.168.50.117:5000/v2/internet-crawler/tags/list" | jq -r '.tags[0]'
2.9.6
```

Comment: tks you so much, i understand it

Comment: @NamPhan You can use `tags=$(curl -X GET "192.168.50.117:5000/v2/internet-crawler/tags/list" | jq -r '.tags[0]')` to assign `2.9.6` to `tags`.

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    53  100    53    0     0  17666      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 26500
2.9.6
i use that and have this , how can i remove first 3 row

Comment: @NamPhan Still the value of `tags` is `2.9.6` and can be confirmed if you use that value elsewhere. You can disable the progress meter with `s` option of curl. Try `tags=$(curl -sX GET "192.168.50.117:5000/v2/internet-crawler/tags/list" | jq -r '.tags[0]')`.